# Run-Time Check Failure #0 in dll value ESP not saved

Tags: c++, dll, runtime, visual-studio-2019

I cannot seem to figure out why its doing this...

```
unsigned long drawing::font;
auto drawing::setup_fonts() -> void
{
    drawing::font = g_surface->CreateFont_();
    g_surface->SetFontGlyphSet(drawing::font, "Small Fonts", 8, 400, 0, 0, sdk::FONTFLAG_OUTLINE);
}

auto drawing::render_text(int x, int y, Color clr, const char* fmt, ...) -> void
{
    va_list va_alist;
    char buffer[1024] = { '\0' };
    wchar_t str[1024] = { '\0' };

    va_start(va_alist, fmt);
    vsprintf(buffer, fmt, va_alist);
    va_end(va_alist);

    swprintf(str, 1024, L"%s", buffer);

    g_surface->DrawSetTextPos(x, y);
    g_surface->DrawSetTextFont(drawing::font);
    g_surface->DrawSetTextColor(clr);
    g_surface->DrawPrintText(str, wcslen(str));
}
```

it is giving me this error in both functions, second one is at the closing bracket and first error is this line

```
drawing::font = g_surface->CreateFont_();
```

namespace drawing def

```
namespace drawing
{
    auto setup_fonts() -> void;
    auto render_text(int x, int y, Color clr, const char* fmt, ...) -> void;
    extern unsigned long font;
}
```

g_surface def

```
sdk::ISurface* g_surface;
extern sdk::ISurface*         g_surface;

g_surface = get_interface<sdk::ISurface>("vguimatsurface.dll", VGUIMAT_SURFACE_INTERFACE_VERSION);


template <class T>
auto get_interface(const char* module, const char* name) -> T*
{
    return reinterpret_cast<T*>(platform::get_interface(module, name));
}
```

and ISurface class. its telling me to add more info because of how big this class is so i removed most of it

```
class ISurface
    {
    public:
        ...
        virtual vgui::HFont   CreateFont_() = 0;
        virtual bool          SetFontGlyphSet(vgui::HFont font, const char* windowsFontName, int tall, int weight, int blur, int scanlines, int flags, int nRangeMin = 0, int nRangeMax = 0) = 0;
        ...
    };
```

in debugger I checked if g_surface was nullptr and its not.

Comment: Possibly a different calling convention in the DLL than what you're assuming.

Comment: i have other interfaces that i access the same way and are defined the same way. This interface is even accessed somewhere else in the code. Could it possibly be a linker issue?

Comment: It may be a linker problem, you could check whether the connected dll is correct.